# Left align the title of sections and subsections

Tags: sectioning, alignment

I want the titles of sections and subsection to align on the same line (red in the picture):

[image]

How can I do it, preferably, without a package (titlesec for example)? I.e., by modifying the commands `\@seccntformat` and/or `\@startsection`?

In the following MWE, I insert the same `\hskip` after `\thesection` AND `\thesubsection`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\hskip 15pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{one}
\subsection{a}
Lorem ipsum, text text text
\section{two}
\subsection{b}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate a fixed amount of space for the (sub)section counter typesetting.  Here I chose 40pt; however, if your section or subsection numbering extend into double digits, you may need to revise that value.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \makebox[40pt][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{one}
\subsection{a}
Lorem ipsum, text text text
\section{two}
\subsection{b}
\end{document}
```

[image]